# Why I can't create Face3 in ThreeJS Typescript project

Tags: typescript, three.js, geometry, mesh, face

I am trying to create Mesh by using Face3. I am using Threejs in typescript project. There are several problems I am facing.

```
const points = [
     new Face3(-1, 1, -1),//c
     new Face3(-1, -1, 1),//b
     new Face3(1, 1, 1),//a

     new Face3(1, 1, 1),//a
     new Face3(1, -1, -1),//d
     new Face3(-1, 1, -1),//c

     new Face3(-1, -1, 1),//b
     new Face3(1, -1, -1),//d
     new Face3(1, 1, 1),//a

     new Face3(-1, 1, -1),//c
     new Face3(1, -1, -1),//d
     new Face3(-1, -1, 1),//b
]
let geometry = new Geometry();
for (const point of points) {
     geometry.faces.push(point);
}
```

First of all, I can't add this **geometry** into mesh. It gives me error that it is not a **BufferGeometry**

[image]

If I try to create a new BufferGeometry from Geomtery, I can't find property **fromGeometry**

[image]

If these kind of functions has been deprecated, then what is the exact alternative for this? Why there is no proper guideline or instruction available?
Is there anyone who can suggest me better solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The class `THREE.Geometry` has been removed form core since `r125` and was moved to `examples/jsm/deprecated/Geometry.js`. `THREE.Face` can be imported from the same module.

Notice that it is not recommended to work with `THREE.Geometry` anymore. It's best to focus on `THREE.BufferGeometry`. The following topic at the `three.js` forum provides more background information: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-geometry-will-be-removed-from-core-with-r125/22401